# I can't get Chrome to emulate touch events anymore

Tags: touch, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome updated to 36.0.1985.125 and "Emulate Touch Events" seems to have stopped working. I don't even see the check box that is supposed to enable it.
I tried the Canary channel, but I can't find it there either.
How do I get it working again?

**EDIT:**
The option reappeared in the Canary channel, but not in the stable one. I'm guessing they're trying to fix the implementation and decided to turn it off until it's working the way it should.